# ng-repeat inside ng-repeat with td for each item - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

This code gives me a table with the elements in a single column.

Here data will be like this

```
var data = [[{"id":"1","value":"One"},{"id":"2","value":"Two"},{"id":"3","value":"three"}],[{"id":"4","value":"four"},{"id":"5","value":"five"},{"id":"6","value":"six"}],[{"id":"7","value":"seven"},{"id":"8","value":"eigth"},{"id":"9","value":"nine"}]]

<div id="mydiv">
    <table>
       <tr ng-repeat="rows in data">
           <td ng-repeat="item in rows">{{item.id}}:{{item.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This gives me a table with three column. Like

```
1:One 2:Two 3:three
4:four 5:five 6:six
7:seven . . .
```

Along with this I want the table with `item.id` in one column `:` in one column and `item.value` in one column for better readability and not in a single column.

Tried to do that but am not able to get it working, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Just to check that my understanding is correct - there are three elements in each row, right?

Comment: I've updated my question with data @dev-null

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should define your table this way:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="rows in data">
            <td ng-repeat-start="item in rows">{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td ng-repeat-end>{{item.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

For more information see the [**Special repeat start and end points** section of the ngRepeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> To repeat a series of elements instead of just one parent element, ngRepeat (as well as other ng directives) supports extending the range of the repeater by defining explicit start and end points by using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end respectively. The ng-repeat-start directive works the same as ng-repeat, but will repeat all the HTML code (including the tag it's defined on) up to and including the ending HTML tag where ng-repeat-end is placed.

Comment: Do you consider this answer the correct answer of your question ? If yes can you mark it as the correct answer to help others when they read your question ?

Comment: And what if some of the rows don't have items in it ? Basically, I have this table which contains certain categories. Some of them have subcategories, some don't. How could I put the code in my html ? As for the structure of the array I loop in, it looks like this :
{name : 'name_category', subcategories:{}}
Obviously some of the objects have the subcategories array empty